# How to use LibraryLink to send an Image OR an Image3D as input?

Tags: librarylink

The problem I am facing is the following. I need to have as input to my LibraryFunction and 2D or 3D image. Using the following syntax

```
$FunctionBlabla= safeLibraryFunctionLoad[debug,"FunctionBlabla",{"UTF8String"}, LibraryDataType[Image|Image3D]];
```

It is possible to return either an Image or an Image3D depending on some conditions in your function `FunctionBlabla`. I want to know if it's also possible to something like that in the output? This syntax doesn't work.

```
$FunctionBlabla= safeLibraryFunctionLoad[debug,"FunctionBlabla",{LibraryDataType[Image|Image3D]}, LibraryDataType[Image|Image3D]];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? `LibraryDataType[Image|Image3D]` is the correct way to do this, and it works for me.  `Image|Image3D` also works as a shorthand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: The question has an answer. It is probably a year old. I'm fine closing it. Or I can just delete it if you'd like

Comment: I voted to close because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem, and because I do not believe that the problem was what the answer would suggest.  It can be reopened if you show how to reproduce the problem. Then we can try to tease out the real cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as writing

```
$FunctionBlabla= safeLibraryFunctionLoad[debug,"FunctionBlabla",{{"Image" | "Image3D"}}, LibraryDataType[Image|Image3D]];
```